Getting correct kobject for sysfs_notify()
I'm working on a PMBus device driver kernel module.  (This is my first kernel module, so please be nice.)  I've added a GPIO interrupt handler which just keeps track of the number of edges received on the GPIO pin, and I've added a sysfs entry to display the number of events that have occurred. This functionality works perfectly.
However, within the interrupt handler, I would like to add a sysfs_notify() call so that user-space code can poll() the sysfs file that's keeping track of edges. Unfortunately, the poll is not working, and I believe it's because I am feeding the wrong kobject to sysfs_notify().
struct tps25990_data {
    struct device *dev;
    struct pmbus_driver_info info;
    ...
    unsigned int num_gpio_faults;
};
...
static ssize_t num_gpio_faults_show(struct device *dev,
              struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{

    struct i2c_client *client = to_i2c_client(dev->parent);
    const struct pmbus_driver_info *info = pmbus_get_driver_info(client);
    struct tps25990_data *data = to_tps25990_data(info);

    return sysfs_emit(buf, "%d\n", data->num_gpio_faults);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR_RO(num_gpio_faults);

static struct attribute *attributes[] = {
    &dev_attr_num_gpio_faults.attr,
    NULL,
};

static const struct attribute_group attr_group = {
    .attrs  = attributes,
};

static const struct attribute_group *tps25990_attribute_groups[] = {
    &attr_group,
    NULL,
};

...
static irqreturn_t efuse_fault_gpio_irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id){
    struct tps25990_data *data = dev_id;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Efuse fault detected on gpio%d\n", desc_to_gpio(data->fault_gpio));
    data->num_gpio_faults++;
    const char *path;
    path = kobject_get_path(&data->dev->kobj, GFP_KERNEL);
    dev_info(data->dev, "efuse_fault_gpio_irq_handler Path = %s\n", path);
    kfree(path);
    sysfs_notify(&data->dev->kobj, NULL, "num_gpio_faults");
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int tps25990_probe(struct i2c_client *client)
{
    ...
    struct tps25990_data *data;
    struct pmbus_driver_info *info;
    ...
    data = devm_kzalloc(&client->dev, sizeof(struct tps25990_data), GFP_KERNEL);
    data->dev = &client->dev;
    info = &data->info;
    info->groups = tps25990_attribute_groups;
    ...
    data->fault_gpio  = devm_gpiod_get_optional(&client->dev, "fault", GPIOD_IN);
    if (data->fault_gpio) {
        gpiod_set_consumer_name(data->fault_gpio, "EFUSE FAULT");
        data->fault_gpio_irq = gpiod_to_irq(data->fault_gpio);
        if (data->fault_gpio_irq < 0) {
            dev_err(&client->dev, "No corresponding irq for fault-gpio\n");
            return data->fault_gpio_irq;
        }
        ret = irq_set_irq_type(data->fault_gpio_irq, IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING);
        ret = devm_request_threaded_irq(&client->dev,
                data->fault_gpio_irq,
                NULL,
                efuse_fault_gpio_irq_handler,
                0,
                "efuse fault",
                info);
        if (ret) {
            dev_info(&client->dev, "Failed to request fault-gpio irq (code: %d)\n", ret);
            irq_dispose_mapping(data->fault_gpio_irq);
            return ret;
        }
    } else {
        dev_info(&client->dev, "No fault-gpio found in device tree\n");
    }

    data->num_gpio_faults = 0;

    ret = pmbus_do_probe(client, info);
    ...
}

Once this module is running, I can call cat num_gpio_faults in the appropriate sysfs directory.  The correct number of event edges is displayed, and dmesg shows:
[  233.630694] hwmon hwmon3: num_gpio_faults_show Path = /devices/platform/soc/fe804000.i2c/i2c-1/i2c-22/22-0046/hwmon/hwmon3

However, when I generate an edge to fire the interrupt, dmesg shows:
[  245.874307] Efuse fault detected on gpio579
[  245.874342] tps25990 22-0046: efuse_fault_gpio_irq_handler Path = /devices/platform/soc/fe804000.i2c/i2c-1/i2c-22/22-0046

So, it appears that whatever struct device is being fed to the interrupt handler (which is the struct device contained in the i2c_client) is different from the struct device that is fed to my num_gpio_faults_show() function.  The struct device that is fed to my num_gpio_faults_show() function appears to have the full path in the kobject.  However, I haven't been able to determine how to get that correct struct device fed to my interrupt handler in order to have the correct kobject to send with sysfs_notify().
I believe that the correct struct device is the hwmon_dev item that is within struct pmbus_data.  However, that struct is not exported and not available in my module.
Any suggestions?
I've tried using the i2c_client device but it has the incorrect kobject.

IIRC. poll() is disabled for the entire sysfs. You may read the kernfs source code and see what file operations it does support. (It has some stub for .poll IIRC, but better just go and read the real code).

poll works just fine once the correct handle is passed to sysfs_notify.  Unfortunately the only way I've found to get the correct handle is the "hack" solution below.

Okay, here is the explanation how it’s supposed to work:  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/kernfs/file.c#L823

And here is an example on how to call notification from an interrupt handler: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/hwmon/gpio-fan.c#L51

Well I've found a solution, but I'm sure it's not an advisable way to do it. I've added this snippet to my probe function. Here I've used sysfs_get_dirent() to traverse the subdirectories associated with my struct device.  I've added the correct kobject as part of my driver data (data->hwmon_kobj), and now in my interrupt handler I can call sysfs_notify(data->hwmon_kobj, NULL, "num_gpio_faults"). This works as intended. I hate this solution because it assumes a priori knowledge of the subdirectory names (here I know that the subdirectory is named ".../hwmon/hwmon3") and it uses the priv member of the kernfs_node (which I'm sure is a no-no).  Anyone with a better idea?  Is there a more acceptable way to recursively search through subdirectories for a kobject?
struct kernfs_node* kn = sysfs_get_dirent(data->dev->kobj.sd, "hwmon");

if (!kn) {
    dev_err(data->dev, "Failed to get hwmon kn\n");
} else {
    struct kobject *kobj = (struct kobject *)(kn->priv);

    if (!kobj) {
        dev_err(data->dev, "Failed to get hwmon kobj\n");
    } else {
        char hwmon_subdir[8];
        struct kernfs_node* subdir_kn;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            sprintf(hwmon_subdir, "hwmon%d", i);
            subdir_kn = sysfs_get_dirent(kobj->sd, hwmon_subdir);
            if (subdir_kn)
                break;
        }

        if (!subdir_kn) {
            dev_err(data->dev, "Failed to get hmwon subdirectory kn\n");
        } else {
            data->hwmon_kobj = (struct kobject *)(subdir_kn->priv);
            if (!data->hwmon_kobj) {
                dev_err(data->dev, "Failed to get hmwon subdirectory kobj\n");
            } else {
                const char *path = kobject_get_path(data->hwmon_kobj, GFP_KERNEL);

                dev_info(data->dev, "hwmon subdirectory path: %s\n", path);
                kfree(path);
            }
        }
    }
}


Like you said, this is a big hack and not a solution.

Agreed.  That's kind of what I do.
